# Cannot load InvenSense's MotionDriver firmware

Tags: c, microcontroller, firmware, mpu6050

I am trying to read data from the DMP of the MPU-6050 using InvenSense's motion driver 6.12.

```
// ...

#define DEFAULT_MPU_HZ  100

void die(const char* message) {
    fprintf(stderr, message);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void) {
    if(mpu_init(NULL)) {
        die("could not initialize MPU!\n");
    }

    if(mpu_set_sensors(INV_XYZ_GYRO | INV_XYZ_ACCEL)) {
        die("could not turn on sensors!\n");
    }

    if(mpu_configure_fifo(INV_XYZ_GYRO | INV_XYZ_ACCEL)) {
        die("could not configure FIFO buffer\n");
    }

    if(mpu_set_sample_rate(DEFAULT_MPU_HZ)) {
        die("could not set sample rate\n");
    }

    if(mpu_set_gyro_fsr(2000)) {
        die("could not set gyro full scale range!\n");
    }

    if(mpu_set_accel_fsr(2)) {
        die("could not set accel full scale range!\n");
    }

    if(dmp_load_motion_driver_firmware()) {
        die("[ERROR] dmp_load_motion_driver_firmware\n");
    }

    // ....

}
```

This code is also from the motion driver source code.

After initializing the mpu I am calling `dmp_load_motion_driver_firmware();` which looks like this.

```
/**
 *  @brief      Load and verify DMP image.
 *  @param[in]  length      Length of DMP image.
 *  @param[in]  firmware    DMP code.
 *  @param[in]  start_addr  Starting address of DMP code memory.
 *  @param[in]  sample_rate Fixed sampling rate used when DMP is enabled.
 *  @return     0 if successful.
 */
int mpu_load_firmware(unsigned short length, const unsigned char *firmware,
    unsigned short start_addr, unsigned short sample_rate)
{
    unsigned short ii;
    unsigned short this_write;
    /* Must divide evenly into st.hw->bank_size to avoid bank crossings. */
#define LOAD_CHUNK  (16)
    unsigned char cur[LOAD_CHUNK], tmp[2];

    if (st.chip_cfg.dmp_loaded)
        /* DMP should only be loaded once. */
        return -1;

    if (!firmware)
        return -1;
    for (ii = 0; ii < length; ii += this_write) {
        this_write = min(LOAD_CHUNK, length - ii);
        if (mpu_write_mem(ii, this_write, (unsigned char*)&firmware[ii]))
            return -1;
        if (mpu_read_mem(ii, this_write, cur))
            return -1;
        if (memcmp(firmware+ii, cur, this_write))
            return -2;
    }

    /* Set program start address. */
    tmp[0] = start_addr >> 8;
    tmp[1] = start_addr & 0xFF;
    if (i2c_write(st.hw->addr, st.reg->prgm_start_h, 2, tmp))
        return -1;

    st.chip_cfg.dmp_loaded = 1;
    st.chip_cfg.dmp_sample_rate = sample_rate;
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see this writes the firmware to the MPU, reads back the data and checks if they match. Unfortunately they don't match and I don't know why. The value read by `mpu_read_mem` looks like this

```
foo = {unsigned char [16]} 
 [0] = {unsigned char} 0 '\000'
 [1] = {unsigned char} 255 '�'
 [2] = {unsigned char} 255 '�'
 [3] = {unsigned char} 255 '�'
 [4] = {unsigned char} 255 '�'
 [5] = {unsigned char} 255 '�'
 [6] = {unsigned char} 255 '�'
 [7] = {unsigned char} 255 '�'
 [8] = {unsigned char} 255 '�'
 [9] = {unsigned char} 255 '�'
 [10] = {unsigned char} 255 '�'
 [11] = {unsigned char} 255 '�'
 [12] = {unsigned char} 255 '�'
 [13] = {unsigned char} 255 '�'
 [14] = {unsigned char} 255 '�'
 [15] = {unsigned char} 255 '�'
```

There are some posts at the official developers forum with the exact same problem but none of them provide an solution for this problem.

Maybe some of you had the same problem and can help me.

Comment: Without your actual initialization code, it's impossible to tell what's wrong, since the code you posted is an existing driver function. Have you compared your code to [these functions](https://github.com/search?q=dmp_load_motion_driver_firmware&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93), for example? Or checked some [existing projects](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=MPU-6050&type=)?

Comment: I improved my question and added my initialization code

Comment: I've tried the same code above with the RasperryPi 3 and i2cdevlib and it works. With the Adafruit FT232H it won't. Maybe this is some kind of hardware or driver error? Any hints how to go on?